# Expected Value with Cards

Tags: probability

The cards of a standard 52-card deck are dealt out in a circle. What is the expected number of pairs of adjacent cards which are both black? Express your answer as a common fraction.

I really have no idea how to start. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to get you started:

- Use indicator variable.
- Focus on a pair of card, what is the probability that both are black.

Edit:

Let's introduce the indicator variable $X_i$ such that it is equal to $1$ when it is black and the very next card (counter clockwise) is black as well and it is equal to $0$ otherwise.

Then the number of pairs of adjacent cards which are both black is $\sum_{i=1}^{52} X_i$ and its expected value is $$\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{52} X_i\right] =\sum_{i=1}^{52} \mathbb{E} \left[X_i\right] =\sum_{i=1}^{52} \frac12 \cdot \frac{25}{51} =\frac{26\cdot 25}{51}=\frac{650}{51}$$

Comment: I don't know what an indicator variable is :/. But I do know that in a pair of cards the prob. that both are black is 1/4

Comment: @TheLeogend An indicator random variable, also called a Bernoulli random variable or binary random variable, is one where it takes value $1$ for a respective event and value $0$ otherwise.  I.e. $X_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if the}~n\text{'th and}~(n+1)\text{'st cards are both black}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: Letting $X$ be the random variable counting the total number of pairs of adjacent cards of which both are black, compare $X$ to $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$.  How are these related?

Comment: Note that due to the cards are dealt without replacement, the probability is not $\frac14$, it is closed to it though.

Comment: Also, the thing about indicator random variables is that $\mathsf E(X_n) = 1\mathsf P(X_n=1)\require{cancel}\cancel{+0\mathsf P(X_n=0)}$.

Comment: Would anyone be able to give a full solution? I cannot make an progress :(

Comment: include whatever you have? then we can try to help you out from there.

Comment: So the probability that both are black is 1/2 * 25/51. Now, let me work on indicator variable

Comment: I edited the answer to include more details.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Also, this question has an intuitive answer: Each black card has 25/51 chance of another black card to its right. So the answer is also 25/51 *26, since each black card "contributes" that much. Is this linearty of expectation here?

Comment: yes, it is just linearity.